# Beginner Python - Printing 3 different responses based on age using a while loop

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

**Teaching myself Python out of a book and I'm stuck on this exercise:**
A movie theater charges different ticket prices depending on a person’s age. If a person is under the age of 3, the ticket is free; if they are between 3 and 12, the ticket is $10; and if they are over age 12, the ticket is $15. Write a loop in which you ask users their age, and then tell them the cost of their movie ticket.

I know how to make it work without using a loop but I am a uncertain how to make it work using a while loop. Any advice or examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show what you've tried and and you're likely to get more help, you probably just need to include a forever loop, e.g. `while True:`.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be an infinite loop. Don't forget to include a break condition, otherwise you won't be able to exit your program gracefully.

```
while True:
    userinput = int(input())
    if userinput < 0:
        break

    # your if logic goes here
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out on my own

```
prompt = "\nEnter 'quit' when you are finished."
prompt += "\nPlease enter your age: "


while True:
    age = input(prompt)
    age = int(age)


    if age == 'quit':
        break
    elif age <= 3:
        print("Your ticket is free")
    elif age <= 10:
        print("Your ticket is $10")
    else:
        print("Your ticket is $15")
```

Comment: Actually this didn't work 100%...the quit function won't work because it is not an integer. So this brings up a new question: How to get it to work with both an integer answer and a string answer?

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it would be creating an infinite loop like such:

```
price = -1
while price == -1:
   try:
       age=int(raw_input('Age: '))
   except ValueError:
        print "Not a number, try again."
        continue

   if age <= 3:
       price = 0
   elif age > 3 and age < 12:
       price = 10
   else:
       price = 15

print "The price will be "+str(price)+"$."
```

Note:
Rename raw_input() to input() if you are using Python 3.

Comment: Didn't work - Traceback (most recent call last):
 line 4, in <module>
    age=int(raw_input('Age: '))
NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Are you using Python 3? 

raw_input() was renamed to input() in Python 3

From http://docs.python.org/dev/py3k/whatsnew/3.0.html

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but none of the answers seemed great. So here's my solution to 7-5/ 7-6

```
loop = True
#while loop = true run 'while loop'
while loop:
#Print message
    print ('Please enter your age.')
#receive input from user
    age = raw_input()
#check if the user input "quit" if so end loop. Break ends program but should be replaceable by
#if age == 'quit':
#   loop = False
#resulting the the same effect (ending loop)
    if age == 'quit':
        break
#Convert age input by user to int so it is recognized as a number by python
    age = int(age)
#If/ elif pretty self explanatory   
    if age < 3:
        price = 5
    elif age < 12:
        price = 10
    elif age > 12:
        price = 15
    else:
        print('Input not recognized')
        break
#Print ticket price based on age and ask user if they need another price/inform them how to exit program        
    print('Your ticked price is $' + str(price) + '.')
    print('\n If you would like to check the price for another person please enter their age now or type "quit" to exit')
```

The formatting might be a little off since it pasted oddly. I tried to explain what everything does. Also I use 2.7 instead of 3 so if you're using python 3 replace raw_input() with input()

Hopefully this answer was helpful to some on. GL with programming.

Answer (score 0):

```
prompt = "How old are you? "
prompt += "\nEnter 'quit' when you are finished. "

while True:
    age = input(prompt)
    if age == 'quit':
        break
    age = int(age)

    if age < 3:
        print("Your ticket is free. Congratulations")
    elif age < 13:
        print("Your ticket is $10 dollars")
    else:
        print("Your ticket is $15 dollars")
```

Comment: Changed to INT after the break so it could first read 'quit' and then read age as a number.

Comment: Do you mind editing your answer with further explanation of your approach, and how it differs from the existing approaches? That’s always valuable, but especially when answering a four year old question with existing contributions.

Answer (score 0):

```
prompt = "\nPlease enter 'done' when finished! "
prompt += "\nPlease enter your age:"

while True:
    try:
        age = input(prompt)
        if age == 'done':
            break

        age = int(age)
        if age <= 3:
            print("Free ticket")
        elif age in range(4, 12):
            print("You must pay 10$")
        elif age >= 12:
            print("You must pay 15$")
    except ValueError:
        continue
```